# Pyspark: Filter dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, pyspark, filter, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter dataframe according to the following conditions firstly (d<5)  and  secondly (value of col2 not equal its counterpart in col4 if value in col1 equal its counterpart in col3).

If the original dataframe `DF` is as follows:

```python
+----+----+----+----+---+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|  d|
+----+----+----+----+---+
|   A|  xx|   D|  vv|  4|
|   C| xxx|   D|  vv| 10|
|   A|   x|   A|  xx|  3|
|   E| xxx|   B|  vv|  3|
|   E| xxx|   F| vvv|  6|
|   F|xxxx|   F| vvv|  4|
|   G| xxx|   G| xxx|  4|
|   G| xxx|   G|  xx|  4|
|   G| xxx|   G| xxx| 12|
|   B|xxxx|   B|  xx| 13|
+----+----+----+----+---+
```

The desired Dataframe is:

```python
+----+----+----+----+---+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|  d|
+----+----+----+----+---+
|   A|  xx|   D|  vv|  4|
|   A|   x|   A|  xx|  3|
|   E| xxx|   B|  vv|  3|
|   F|xxxx|   F| vvv|  4|
|   G| xxx|   G|  xx|  4|
+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Code I have tried that did not work as expected:

```python
cols=[('A','xx','D','vv',4),('C','xxx','D','vv',10),('A','x','A','xx',3),('E','xxx','B','vv',3),('E','xxx','F','vvv',6),('F','xxxx','F','vvv',4),('G','xxx','G','xxx',4),('G','xxx','G','xx',4),('G','xxx','G','xxx',12),('B','xxxx','B','xx',13)]
df=spark.createDataFrame(cols,['col1','col2','col3','col4','d'])

df.filter((df.d<5)& (df.col2!=df.col4) & (df.col1==df.col3)).show()

+----+----+----+----+---+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|  d|
+----+----+----+----+---+
|   A|   x|   A|  xx|  3|
|   F|xxxx|   F| vvv|  4|
|   G| xxx|   G|  xx|  4|
+----+----+----+----+---+
```

What should I do to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Your logic condition is wrong. IIUC, what you want is:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.filter((f.col('d')<5))\
    .filter(
        ((f.col('col1') != f.col('col3')) | 
         (f.col('col2') != f.col('col4')) & (f.col('col1') == f.col('col3')))
    )\
    .show()
```

I broke the `filter()` step into 2 calls for readability, but you could equivalently do it in one line.

Output:

```python
+----+----+----+----+---+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|  d|
+----+----+----+----+---+
|   A|  xx|   D|  vv|  4|
|   A|   x|   A|  xx|  3|
|   E| xxx|   B|  vv|  3|
|   F|xxxx|   F| vvv|  4|
|   G| xxx|   G|  xx|  4|
+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Answer (score 38):

You can also write like below (without `pyspark.sql.functions`):

```
df.filter('d<5 and (col1 <> col3 or (col1 = col3 and col2 <> col4))').show()
```

Result:

```
+----+----+----+----+---+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|  d|
+----+----+----+----+---+
|   A|  xx|   D|  vv|  4|
|   A|   x|   A|  xx|  3|
|   E| xxx|   B|  vv|  3|
|   F|xxxx|   F| vvv|  4|
|   G| xxx|   G|  xx|  4|
+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Answer (score 12):

faster way (without `pyspark.sql.functions`)

```
    df.filter((df.d<5)&((df.col1 != df.col3) |
                    (df.col2 != df.col4) & 
                    (df.col1 ==df.col3)))\
    .show()
```

Comment: This way `df` must be repeated.

Comment: @ZygD is there an issue if `df` gets repeated? Does it lead to slower perf than using `f.col()`

Comment: @insanely_sin - when you decide to change the name of `df` to something more descriptive, you will have to do it for every instance.

Answer (score 4):

I am late to the party, but someone might find this useful.

If your conditions were to be in a list form e.g. `filter_values_list =['value1', 'value2']` and you are filtering on a single column, then you can do:

```py
df.filter(df.colName.isin(filter_values_list)  #in case of == 
df.filter(~df.colName.isin(filter_values_list) #in case of !=
```