# How to drop columns based on multiple filters in a dataframe using PySpark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list of valid values that a cell can have. If one cell in a column is invalid, I need to drop the whole column. I understand there are answers of dropping rows in a particular column but here I am dropping the whole column instead even if one cell in it is invalid. The conditions for valid/invalid are that a cell can have only three values: `['Messi', 'Ronaldo', 'Virgil']`

I tried reading about filtering but all I could see was filtering columns and dropping the rows. For instance in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301373/pyspark-filter-dataframe-based-on-multiple-conditions) question. I also read that one should avoid too much scanning and shuffling in Spark, which I agree with.

I am not only looking at the code solution but more on the off-the-shelf code provided from PySpark. I hope it doesn't get out of the scope of a SO answer.

For the following input dataframe:

```
| Column 1      | Column 2      | Column 3      | Column 4      | Column 5      |
| --------------| --------------| --------------| --------------| --------------|
|  Ronaldo      | Salah         |  Messi        |               |Salah          |
|  Ronaldo      | Messi         |  Virgil       |  Messi        | null          |
|  Ronaldo      | Ronaldo       |  Messi        |  Ronaldo      | null          |
```

I expect the following output:

```
| Column 1      | Column 2      |
| --------------| --------------| 
|  Ronaldo      | Messi         |
|  Ronaldo      | Virgil        |
|  Ronaldo      | Messi         |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am not only looking at the code solution but more on the off-the-shelf code provided from PySpark.

Unfortunately, Spark is designed to operate in parallel on a row-by-row basis. Filtering out columns is not something for which there will be an "off-the-shelf code" solution.

Nevertheless, here is one approach you can take:

First collect the counts of the invalid elements in each column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, sum as _sum, when

valid = ['Messi', 'Ronaldo', 'Virgil']
invalid_counts = df.select(
    *[_sum(when(col(c).isin(valid), lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1))).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
).collect()
print(invalid_counts)
#[Row(Column 1=0, Column 2=1, Column 3=0, Column 4=1, Column 5=3)]
```

This output will be a list with only one element. You can iterate over the items in this element to find the columns to keep.

```
valid_columns = [k for k,v in invalid_counts[0].asDict().items() if v == 0]
print(valid_columns)
#['Column 3', 'Column 1']
```

Now just select these columns from your original DataFrame. You can first sort `valid_columns` using `list.index` if you want to maintain the original column order.

```
valid_columns = sorted(valid_columns, key=df.columns.index)
df.select(valid_columns).show()
#+--------+--------+
#|Column 1|Column 3|
#+--------+--------+
#| Ronaldo|   Messi|
#| Ronaldo|  Virgil|
#| Ronaldo|   Messi|
#+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks @pault

In case anyone wants the complete shell interaction, click [here](https://pastebin.com/YeYyWpv9).