# how to filter a spark dataframe by two boolean column

Tags: user-defined-functions, pyspark

So I have a dataframe table call latest_key_status, it have two boolean column 'a' and 'b' 
When I want to filter it by 'a', like this:

```
latest_key_status.filter(latest_key_status['a'] == False)
```

It works

However, when I want to do this

```
latest_key_status.filter((latest_key_status['a'] == False) | (latest_key_status['b'] == False))
```

It failed

Could anyone tell me how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301373/pyspark-filter-dataframe-based-on-multiple-conditions

Comment: by [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) you should be able to do `latest_key_status.filter(~(latest_key_status['a']&latest_key_status['b']))`